# How can I debug this Java code -- a POST request

Tags: java, html, forms, post

I have the following code, which is my attempt to fill out a POST body and submit.

```
//get myIP as var via InetAddress and getHostAddress

String query =  URLEncoder.encode("ip!0", "UTF-8") +"=" + URLEncoder.encode(myIP, "UTF-8")
+ "&"+ URLEncoder.encode("abuse_address!0", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("abuse@123test", "UTF-8")
+ "&" +URLEncoder.encode("admin_username!0", "UTF-8") + " =" + URLEncoder.encode("admin", "UTF-8") 
+ "&" +URLEncoder.encode("admin_password!0", "UTF-8") + "="+ URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("http://xx.x.x.xx/index.ws3?25334cvvssd522afmkkllmk"); // url has a unique hash

URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(query);
out.flush();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Now when I run this, it is not posting, as the new entry doesn't show up on the webpage. The while loop that prints every line of the input stream echos what looks basically like the page source. I'll put it here:

```
<html>
        <head>
    //scripts
<body>
</table><br>
    <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="hosts_save"> <INPUT type="button" ONCLICK="history.go(-1)" name="cancel" value="cancel"></input>
    </form>

    <form action="/index.ws3?25334cvvssd522afmkkllmk" method="post">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <THEAD>
<TH>host_id</TH><TH>ip</TH><TH>abuse_address</TH><TH>admin_username</TH><TH>admin_password</TH></THEAD>
<tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" name="ip!0" value="new ip"></input></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" size="45" maxlength="45" name="abuse_address!0" value="new address"></input></td>
            <td><INPUT type="text" size="45" maxlength="100" name="admin_username!0" value="new username"></input></td>
            <td><INPUT type="password" size="45" maxlength="45" name="admin_password!0" value="new password"></input></td>
        </tr>

    </table><br>
        <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="hosts_save"> <INPUT type="button" ONCLICK="history.go(-1)" name="cancel" value="cancel"></input>
    </form>

    </body></html>
```

In this response body, should I expect to see "abuse@123test" and "admin" etc like this? :

```
<INPUT type="text" size="45" maxlength="100" name="admin_username!0" value="admin">admin</input>
```

How can I see a history to see where it is failing? It could be failing from several things. It could not be hitting the right page, it could be passing in the wrong parameters... How can I tell anything that is going on, in order to progress me towards successfully posting?

Comment: Where do you post anything? Why not just use an HTTP client library?

Comment: @DaveNewton from what I understand `out.write(query);` is writing to the output stream. I'm trying not to use outside libraries, but there is no reason not to and if there is an easy to use one that anyone could share I'd try it out. I tried the apache httpclient library and didn't have much luck